# MVC model not bound to collection in POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

- Visual Studio 2012
- MVC 5.2.0
- jQuery 2.1.1
- jQuery UI Combined 1.10.4
- Json.Net 6.0.3
- Kendo UI MVC 2014.1.528

I've read through many similar posts. I've tried to apply what I've seen to no avail. I throw myself at feet of your keyboards for your mercy and help.

I have a survey-like site, so for simplicity here, I made up a sample project to duplicate the issue.  I can upload that too.

I have a model with a **child object of Address** - no problemo there - it binds.

The model also has a **collection of questions**. It never binds on the post, and this is the issue here.

Lets start with models:

The Survey itself:

```
public class Survey
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Phone #")]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string ContactMethodPhone { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [StringLength(120)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string ContactMethodEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

and the address:

```
public class Address
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address line 1")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Address line 2")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    [DisplayName(" ")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ApartmentNum { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Tenement { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("City")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Province/State")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Postal/Zip Code")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string MailCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Country")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Country { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> Provinces { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> MailCodes { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> Tenements { get; set; }
}
```

and the questions:

```
 public class Question
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }                        // Question Image
    [DisplayName("Question: ")]
    public string InformationIntakeGroupValue { get; set; } // Question: ie Did you graguate high school 
    public int ImageID_Topic { get; set; } // Topic Image
    [DisplayName("Topic: ")]
    public string InformationIntakeTopicValue { get; set; } // Topic: ie Education
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string InformationIntakeTypeCode { get; set; }   // Type of question (date, bool, text)
    // below not filled by select;
    // the key from the EntityAffilliateIntake record insert
    public int PersonId { get; set; }                       // Person anwering question
    // this is the user response area
    [DisplayName("Answer: ")]
    public string InformationIntakeValue { get; set; }      
    [DisplayName("Choice: ")]
    public string InformationIntakeValueBool { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date: ")]
    public DateTime InformationIntakeValueDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Survey")]
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }

}
```

(Note: fyi, I've tried the models without foreign keys as well - but perhaps it's not defined correctly)

The controller :

```
   // GET: /Inquiry/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var geoIpData = Strings._download_serialized_json_data<GeoData>(StringConstants.UrlForGeoService);

        SurveyModel = new Survey
        {
            Id=1,
            Address = new AddressController().GetAddressModel(geoIpData.country, geoIpData.regionName, geoIpData.city, ""),
            Questions = new QuestionController().GetQuestions(1).ToList()
        };

        return View(SurveyModel);
    }

    // POST: /Inquiry/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id, Name, ContactMethodPhone, ContactMethodEmail, Address, Questions")] Survey survey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int i = 0;
        }
        if (survey.Address.Cities == null)
        {
            survey.Address.Cities = SurveyModel.Address.Cities;
            survey.Address.Countries = SurveyModel.Address.Countries;
            survey.Address.MailCodes = SurveyModel.Address.MailCodes;
            survey.Address.Provinces = SurveyModel.Address.Provinces;
            survey.Address.Tenements = SurveyModel.Address.Tenements;
        }
        if (survey.Questions == null)
        {
            survey.Questions = SurveyModel.Questions;
        }
        return View(survey);
    }
```

The view:

```
@model BindCollection.Models.Survey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

// I use <div class="container">, <fieldset> and <div class="row">
// instead of <div class="form-horizontal"> and <div class="form-group">

<div class="container">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <h4>Survey</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                Your address information:<br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        @* no problem here with address *@
        @{ var vddAddress = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address" } };}
        @Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", Model.Address, @vddAddress)

        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                How we can contact you? :<br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactMethodPhone, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactMethodPhone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactMethodPhone)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactMethodEmail, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactMethodEmail)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactMethodEmail)
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                Some Questions<br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        @*Here is the evil one! Beware!*@
        @{ var vddQuestions = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Questions" } };}
        @Html.Partial("_QuestionsPartial", Model.Questions, @vddQuestions)

        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

The address partial view is insignificant as there's no problem there.

Here's the partial view for the questions:

```
@model IEnumerable<BindCollection.Models.Question>
@using BindCollection
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{
    string CurrentTopic = string.Empty;
    bool FirstTime = true;
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (CurrentTopic != item.InformationIntakeTopicValue)
    {
        CurrentTopic = item.InformationIntakeTopicValue;
        if (!FirstTime)
        {
            FirstTime = false;
            item.InformationIntakeTopicValue = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        item.InformationIntakeTopicValue = string.Empty;
    }
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>item, "Question")
 <br />
 <br />

}
```

and, of course, I made an EditorTemplate for a question, as you can see a few lines above...

```
@model BindCollection.Models.Question

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)       

   @{if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.InformationIntakeTopicValue))
    {
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h4>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InformationIntakeTopicValue, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" })
                </h4>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    }}

    @*type of value to ask for is denoted by item.InformationIntakeTypeCode*@

    <div class="row">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InformationIntakeGroupValue, null)
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                @{

                    var outputBool = false;
                    var outputDate = false;
                    var outputText = false;

                   if(Model.InformationIntakeTypeCode.ToLower().Contains("date") )
                   {
                       outputDate = true;
                   }
                   else if (Model.InformationIntakeTypeCode.ToLower().Contains("bool"))
                   {
                       outputBool = true;
                   }
                   else if (Model.InformationIntakeTypeCode.ToLower().Contains("string"))
                   {
                       outputText = true;
                   }

                }
                @if(outputBool)
                {
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.InformationIntakeValueBool)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style ="width: 100px;", id="InformationIntakeValueBool"+Model.Id.ToString() })
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Please Select...",
                            Value = "0"
                        },
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Yes",
                            Value = "true"
                        },
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "No",
                            Value = "false"
                        }
                    }).Value("0")
                    )
                }
                @if(outputDate)
                {
                    @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.InformationIntakeValueDate)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100px;", id="InformationIntakeValueDate"+Model.Id.ToString() })
                    )
                }
                @if (outputText)
                {
                    @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m.InformationIntakeValue).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 80%;", id="InformationIntakeValue"+Model.Id.ToString()})
                }
            </div>
    </div>
```

So... When I POST, an odd thing occurs. All form values are passed, but the ones for Questions look strange:

```
Id  1
Name    sally
Address.Street  123 Avenue Steet
Address.Street2 Building C
Address.Tenement    Suite
Address.ApartmentNum    111
Address.City_input  Sarnia
Address.City    Sarnia
Address.State_input Ontario
Address.State   Ontario
Address.Country_input   Canada
Address.Country Canada
Address.MailCode_input  N6B 2K0
Address.MailCode    N6B 2K0
ContactMethodPhone  555-555-5555
ContactMethodEmail  r@r.com
Questions.item.Id   1
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueBool   true
Questions.item.Id   2
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueDate   2/4/2014
Questions.item.Id   3
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValue   Speckled
Questions.item.Id   4
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueBool   true
Questions.item.Id   5
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValue   Lightly Toasted
Questions.item.Id   7
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueBool   true
Questions.item.Id   8
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValue   Nothing!
Questions.item.Id   6
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueBool   true
Questions.item.Id   9
Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueDate   6/29/2014
```

I thought, as I've seen in other posts, that the Question items should look like:

```
Questions[0].Id 1
Questions[0].InformationIntakeValueBool true
Questions[1].Id 2
Questions[1].InformationIntakeValueDate 2/4/2014
Questions[2].Id 3
Questions[2].InformationIntakeValue Speckled
```

So I'm not sure why mine looks like this.

On the server side, the Request only shows one variable for each:

```
Request.Form.Results View   Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
    [0] "__RequestVerificationToken"    object {string}
    [1] "Id"    object {string}
    [2] "Name"  object {string}
    [3] "Address.Street"    object {string}
    [4] "Address.Street2"   object {string}
    [5] "Address.Tenement"  object {string}
    [6] "Address.ApartmentNum"  object {string}
    [7] "Address.City_input"    object {string}
    [8] "Address.City"  object {string}
    [9] "Address.State_input"   object {string}
    [10]    "Address.State" object {string}
    [11]    "Address.Country_input" object {string}
    [12]    "Address.Country"   object {string}
    [13]    "Address.MailCode_input"    object {string}
    [14]    "Address.MailCode"  object {string}
    [15]    "ContactMethodPhone"    object {string}
    [16]    "ContactMethodEmail"    object {string}
    [17]    "Questions.item.Id" object {string}
    [18]    "Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueBool" object {string}
    [19]    "Questions.item.InformationIntakeValueDate" object {string}
    [20]    "Questions.item.InformationIntakeValue" object {string}
```

See the last 4 items? What about the other records?

I'm guessing that there's something strange with the ViewDataDictionary that I'm sending to the Question Partial View.

Any help would be appreciated. This **should** be simple...

Comment: Whenever I see a question that says "model not being bound on post" I think "I bet he's using a partial view or a foreach.  95% of the time i'm right.  You're using both.

Comment: ok...and...should no one use partial views? Am I using it wrong? It's an interesting note, but not very useful. I use partial views so that I can reuse that logic elsewhere. My address partial view is used on many forms. I don't have to think about it any more. All addresses are gathered in the same manner. It works.

Comment: Yes, and you have to mess with the HtmlPrefix to make it work.  It's cleaner to just use an EditorTemplate, which does it for you.

Comment: Look above please - I am using an editor template.

Comment: You're a very frustrating person.  You're not using an editor template in the parts you're having problems with.  That's the point.  You're using partials and foreach loops.  Use Editor Templates *instead* of a partial, and use editor templates *instead* of using a foreach because EditorFor will automatically loop through a collection and call your editor template for each item.

Comment: ok! ok!. Sorry for the frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Partial Views or foreach statements contain the necessary information to properly bind collections.  I always use EditorTemplates for everything.  Especially since EditorTemplates will automatically iterate over a collection.

However, if you're bound and determined to use a loop, then use a for loop, and then index the model.  In your case:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    if (CurrentTopic != Model[i].InformationIntakeTopicValue)
    ...
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i]) // don't have to specify the template name
                                   // since it's the same name as the type
}
```

However, i'd just do this:

In your view, do this:

```
@*Here is the evil one! Beware!*@

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)
```

Then have your Question.cshtml as usual, which will automatically get iterated over by the EditorFor

However, at the top of the Question.cshtml (after the model declaration) add the following code, it's all that's necessary to achieve what you're trying to do.  You don't need the partial view at all.

```
@{
  if (ViewBag.CurrentTopic != Model.InformationIntakeTopicValue)
  {
      ViewBag.CurrentTopic = Model.InformationIntakeTopicValue;
  }
  else
  {
      Model.InformationIntakeTopicValue = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do use EditorTemplate - I tried to just use EditorFor without the template name (of the same name as the the type) and it didn't work. It just tried to make up it's own template based on my model. I had to specify the template name.

Comment: I will try to do it without the the partial view at all, with your mod for my empty topic logic.

Comment: If it's not calling your editor template, then there's a reason for that.  Either you're not putting it in the right place, or there is something else going on.

Comment: My editor template does iterate, but I had to force unique control ID's for the Kendo UI library to hook up it's scripts. I'm wondering if this in turn messes up the binding? The 'name' will always be the same, but I need to force the id's to be unique: see  id="InformationIntakeValueBool"+Model.Id.ToString() etc above.

Comment: The app found all the other editor templates (Date/Email/etc) in the Views\Shared\EditorTemplates directory - but not the matching editor for my type. I'll look closer in case I typo'd - Tomorrow I'll upload my test solution.

Comment: You don't need to mess with the id like that.  The ID will be unique because it will contain the proper namespacing from the editor template when you have done it correctly.  Make sure you use the single form for the template Question.cshtml, not Questions.cshtml and double check that you did not misspell it.  The EditorTemplate renders based on the TYPE, not based on the name of the property.

Comment: I removed all ID creation fiddling. I added the code for labelling.  I removed the collection partial view. I just used the EditorFor, without the type name, on the collection in the main razor view. It works as you've suggested it should, even with Kendo. I just need to clean up a few things for style now. Thanks Erik.